# PHP echo hex from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, hex, uuid

In PHP i want to print UUID as text from mysql database

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","user","pass");
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$db_selected = mysql_select_db('advancedban', $con);

$query="SELECT * FROM bm_name_bans";                    
$results = mysql_query($query);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) {
    echo $row['actor_id'];
}
```

Row actor_is is type binary(16) and On website i will get `*?|?O2a?GCtq??I`
can you help me get output `082a3f7c3f4f32613f474374713f3f49`?

Comment: where's the loop for `$row`?

Comment: while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) { echo $row['actor_id']; }

Comment: it should be encoding problem, do you have meta tag with utf-8 encoding?

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not learn the obsolete [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It's awful and has been removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) helps explain best practices. Make **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you will end up with severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: It's probably a better idea to store your UUID values as plain text, typically hex format like `bd6033c3-faad-44dd-9fc9-8723b2cad47c`, because that way you can index them, use those in queries without a lot of fuss, and know at a glance what's going on internally. Using binary values offers very little in the way of benefits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert binary string to hexadecimal string. You can use the combination of `dechex` and `ord` PHP functions like below:

```
$row['actor_id'] = '*?|?O2a?GCtq??I';

for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($row['actor_id']); $i++) {
    $currentChar = $row['actor_id'][$i]; // you can access string characters like it is an array
    echo dechex(ord($currentChar));
}
```

Note that `strlen` is binary safe, and can be used here.